# How to provide JSON inside AWS CLI SNS message?

Tags: json, aws-cli, amazon-sns

How to send via `aws cli` exact JSON structure in command line (NOT via file):

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345:myproject_serverlessscheduler_sns" --message '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' --profile myprofile
```

Is this above a correct structure of JSON provided directly inside command line?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I tried with my SNS topic. The message was properly sent. You have the valid JSON format, so looks like it's a proper format for sending JSON directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSON structure you provided is the correct way of passing JSON inside AWS CLI for SNS.

*I tested on my test environment as shown below and confirmed to be working 100% :*

[image]

Comment: It does not work as intended. It creates the final SNS JSON like this `{"message":"{"key":"value"}"}` instead of `{"message":{"key":"value"}}`. It takes the input JSON as a string instead of the JSON data.